# Can I use the session service directly instead of via the request?

Tags: sessions, http-request, dependency-injection

The [Drupal documentation on sessions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/session/9.3.x) mentions that sessions can be accessed via the Request object:

> Session data is accessed via the
> `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getSession()` method, which
> returns an instance of
> `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface`. The most
> important methods on SessionInterface are set(), get(), and remove().

However I've also dicovered there is a [session service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/service/session/8.2.x).

In a class where I need to use dependency injection and I do not by default have access to the Request object, do I still need to access the session via the request, or can I use it directy? Loading the Request instead and then accessing the session feels like adding overhead.

I have tried below code, which seems to be working fine. So then why do most examples and even the documentation still demonstrate the Request way? Am I missing something, or is there a risk in this approach?

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * The session.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
   */
  protected $session;

  /**
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session $session
   *   The session.
   */
  public function __construct($session) {
    $this->session = $session;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('session')
    );
  }

  function somefunction() {
    $this->session->get('value');
    $this->session->set('value', 'somevalue');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*... is there a risk in this approach?*

If you have multiple requests you could get the wrong session object. Drupal moved a lot of things out of the request object, like routing and even the path info, but they didn't implemented a stacked session service and instead kept the session object in the request stack.

If you want to inject this service there is already a property in [FormBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/class/FormBase/) with getter and setter methods.

This works injected or not (see the comments at the top of the class):

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that the Form already had a method to access the request; that is obviously the cleanest way. I still don't fully get how there can be more sessions for a single user, I'd say that all requests are part of the same session. I can, however, understand that second tabs and AJAX requests might alter the contents of the session.

Comment: For example in a test you could mock a session or another module could run your form in a sub-request with a different session than the main request.